# Batch request for keywordstats?

Tags: facebook, batch-processing, keywordstats

Currently the only way to request keywordstats is for individual adgroups. I'm attempting to retrieve all of the keyword stats for thousands of ads. Is there any way to batch these calls up to speed things up and so I don't hammer the server with so many requests?